# My simple PHP is outputting wrong things

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

**EDIT: I forgot to add semi colons. Now there is another problems. I'm getting a error:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccess.php on line 12
```

It outputs:

```
0){ echo 'si'; } ?>
```

When it should only output 'si' in the body.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
        <? 
            $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["u"])
            $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["p"])

            $query = "SELECT * FROM usario WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'"

            mysql_connect(localhost, "sergio", "123");
            @mysql_select_db("multas") or die( "Unable to select database");

            $result=mysql_query($query);
            if(mysql_numrows($result) > 0){
                echo 'si';
            }   
         ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I was you, I'd count to line 12, then looked for an "Unexpected T_STRING". Seems like you looked for 10seconds before updating the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the "Unexpected T String" error:

The mysql connect statement should read:

```
 mysql_connect('localhost', 'sergio', '123');
```

Comment: Why should it have single quotes?

Comment: @sergia tapia: It's a little better for memory management: in php, if you use double quotes, the string is parsed looking for variables.

Answer (score 4):

That is because you are using short php tags `<?` that most likely are not enabled in php.ini. Try using `<?php` or enable short tags from php.ini but this is not recommended.

Also note that you are missing semi-colon (`;`) fot these lines:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["u"])
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["p"])

$query = "SELECT * FROM usario WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'"
```

Comment: The name of the option to enable short tags is:
'short_open_tag'.

Take a look at this article to see why enabling this is not recommended: http://terrychay.com/article/short_open_tag.shtml

Answer (score 2):

You need semicolons on your $user, $pass, and $query variables.

Answer (score 2):

Missing semi-colon after

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM usario WHERE username = '$user' AND password = '$pass'"
```

Stick quotes around 'localhost'